# How to useState hooks with array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am not able to push the number index in the array of useState.
Where I am going wrong, do I want to push the index of numbers when I click them?
I am extracting the previous state array and then I push new but nothing happens.
How to push a new element inside useState array React hook? My code doesn't work!!
Please someone check.

Game.js

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import RandomNumber from "./RandomNumber";

export default function Game(props) {
  const [state, setstate] = useState([]);
  let randomNumber = Array.from({ length: props.randomNumberCount }).map(
    () => 1 + Math.floor(10 * Math.random())
  );
  let target = randomNumber
    .slice(0, props.randomNumberCount - 2)
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
  const isNumberSelected = (numberIndex) => {
    return state.indexOf(numberIndex) >= 0;
  };
  const selectNumber = (numberIndex) => {
    setstate((arr) => [...arr, numberIndex]);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Target Sum Game</Text>
      <Text style={styles.target}>{target}</Text>
      <View style={styles.randomContainer}>
        {randomNumber.map((randomNumber, index) => (
          <RandomNumber
            key={index}
            id={index}
            number={randomNumber}
            isSelected={isNumberSelected(index)}
            onClick={() => selectNumber}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#ddd",
    paddingTop: 30,
  },
  target: {
    fontSize: 30,
    backgroundColor: "#aaa",
    margin: 50,
    marginHorizontal: 70,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 35,
    backgroundColor: "dodgerblue",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 30,
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  randomContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
  },
});
```

RandomNumber.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default function RandomNumber(props) {
  const handlePress = () => {
    props.onClick(props.id);
  };
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress()}>
      <Text style={[styles.random, props.isSelected && styles.selected]}>
        {props.number}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  random: {
    backgroundColor: "#999",
    width: 100,
    marginHorizontal: 35,
    marginVertical: 25,
    fontSize: 35,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  selected: {
    opacity: 0.3,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not calling the function

```
onClick={() => selectNumber(index)}
```

Comment: if i this according to you i get an error:Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: maybe because you need to write `<TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>`

Comment: workes for me, but i don't know what you want do. it only adds random numbers and selects each index once https://jsfiddle.net/t0po14wj/16/ 
but that is exactly what your code is written for. as you generate new numbers on each rerender.

Comment: if i change this to <TouchableOpacity onPress=()=>{handlePress}>then my number will be selected but number is changing everytime I click

Comment: yeah bro you check once if you select a number then it will be selected but every number is changing

Comment: yes, this is your code. i don't know what you want it to be. but it does exactly what you wrote. what should be the result?

Comment: i want when i select a number it will select and not change other numbers

Comment: you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/k2naLf6c/8/

Comment: yes yes! where should i change my code?

Comment: please help me in my code!

Comment: you can use the code from the jsfiddle. can't write it for react-native as jsfiddle would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the onClick prop and pass the randomNumber (or index depending of what you want to do) to the selectNumber function:

```
// Not sure if you want to pass randonNumber or index but you get the idea
onClick={() => selectNumber(randomNumber)}
```

Comment: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress()}>
```

should be

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>handlePress()}>
```

and

```
() => selectNumber
```

should be

```
() => selectNumber()
```

please try it

Comment: This is working but when i click on any number it got selected but but every number is changing then again and again

Comment: so change ()=>handlePress() to handlePress

Comment: then same problem

Comment: how about : change ()=>handlePress() to handlePress and () => selectNumber()
to selectNumber

Comment: it happens because you regenerate the numbers on each rerender. but that is exactly what your code should do. otherwise you have to change the generation.

Comment: please help me can i share github link for this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Might Be This Helpful:**

**Home.Js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import RandomNumber from './RandomNumber';

const Home = props => {
  const [state, setstate] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('state', state);
  }, [state]);

  let randomNumber = Array.from({length: 10}).map(
    () => 1 + Math.floor(10 * Math.random()),
  );

  let target = randomNumber
    .slice(0, props.randomNumberCount - 2)
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);

  const isNumberSelected = numberIndex => {
    return state.indexOf(numberIndex) >= 0;
  };

  const selectNumber = numberIndex => {
    console.log('numberIndex', numberIndex);
    setstate(arr => [...arr, numberIndex]);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Target Sum Game</Text>
      <Text style={styles.target}>{target}</Text>
      <View style={styles.randomContainer}>
        {randomNumber.map((randomNumber, index) => {
          return (
            <RandomNumber
              key={index}
              id={index}
              number={randomNumber}
              isSelected={isNumberSelected(index)}
              onClick={() => selectNumber(randomNumber)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    paddingTop: 30,
  },
  target: {
    fontSize: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#aaa',
    margin: 50,
    marginHorizontal: 70,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 35,
    backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 30,
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  randomContainer: {},
});

export default Home;
```

**RandomNumber.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default function RandomNumber(props) {
  const handlePress = () => {
    props.onClick(props.id);
  };
  return (
    <View style={{}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress()}>
        <Text style={[styles.random, props.isSelected && styles.selected]}>
          {props.number}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  random: {
    backgroundColor: '#999',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    marginHorizontal: 35,
    marginVertical: 25,
    fontSize: 35,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  selected: {
    opacity: 0.3,
  },
});
```

**Output Log:**

[image: output]